# how can i make the upper case for the full name only

Tags: javascript, html

How can I make the output of the first and last name only upper case? Like it is shown in the picture. I tried doing it but it only works when in the input, not the output.

[image: uppercase]

```js
function myFunction(){
          
var Fname= document.getElementById("fname").value;
var Lname= document.getElementById("lname").value;
var date= document.getElementById("date").value;
var days= document.getElementById("days").value;
var request= document.getElementById("request").value;

var n = document.getElementById("days").value;
var val= document.getElementById("room").value;
var total="";


        if (n<=0){

                n=prompt(" minimum reservation period is 1 day try again");
                }
             
            
         else if (val == "King $30") {
         total = n * 30; 
         } 

         else if (val == "Double $20")  {

         total = n * 20;
         }  

         else   {

         total = n * 10;
         }

  
        
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = " Dear " + Fname + "   " + Lname + " , thank you for booking with us."+
"<br>"+" Expected Arrival Date: " + date +
"<br>" + " Booked: " + val + " room for " + n + " days " +
"<br>" +"Amount=$ " + total +
"<br>" + " Any Special Request: " + request ;
return false;

};
```

```css
body{
background-color:orange;
margin:20px;
}
```

```html
<body>

<h3> Hotel Registration Form </h3>
<p style="color:green">BOOK YOUR STAY WITH US...!</p>


<form>
<label><b> GUEST:</b> </label> 

 <input type="text" id="fname" size="20" > 
 <input type="text" id="lname" size="20" > 
 
 <br>
 <label style="margin-left:65px"> First Name </label>
 <label style="margin-left:105px"> Last Name </label>
 
 <br><br>
 
 <label ><b>Arrival Date:</b></label>
 <input type="date" id="date">
 
 <br><br>
 
 <label><b>Room Type:</b></label>
 
 <select id="room">
 <option></option>
    <option value="King " >King $30</option>
    <option value="Double ">Double $20</option>
    <option value="Single ">Single $10</option>
  </select>
  
  <br><br>
  
  <label><b> Number of Days:</b></label>
  <input type="text" size="12" id="days">

<br><br> 

<label><b> Any Special Request:</b></label>
<br>
<textarea rows="5" cols="50" id="request"></textarea>
  
<br>


<button  type="reset"  STYLE="background-color:red;border:offset;" > CLEAR </button>
<button  type="submit" onClick="return myFunction()" STYLE="background-color:red;border:offset;" > BOOK </button>
</form>

<p style="background-color:#cce6ff;width:350px;font-weight: bold;" id="result">  </p>
```

Comment: You might find CSS [`text-transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform) helpful, e.g. `text-transform: uppercase`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following javascript:

The uppercase function converts to uppercase. There is a native method to convert to uppercase called `toUpperCase()`. More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase)

```js
function myFunction() {

  var Fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  var Lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
  var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
  var days = document.getElementById("days").value;
  var request = document.getElementById("request").value;

  var n = document.getElementById("days").value;
  var val = document.getElementById("room").value;
  var total = "";


  if (n <= 0) {

    n = prompt(" minimum reservation period is 1 day try again");
  } else if (val == "King $30") {
    total = n * 30;
  } else if (val == "Double $20") {

    total = n * 20;
  } else {

    total = n * 10;
  }



  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = " Dear " + capitalize(Fname) + "   " + capitalize(Lname) + ", thank you for booking with us." +
    "<br>" + " Expected Arrival Date: " + date +
    "<br>" + " Booked: " + val + " room for " + n + " days " +
    "<br>" + "Amount=$ " + total +
    "<br>" + " Any Special Request: " + request;
  return false;

};

function capitalize(e) {
  return e.toUpperCase()
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <h3> Hotel Registration Form </h3>
  <p style="color:green">BOOK YOUR STAY WITH US...!</p>


  <form>
    <label><b> GUEST:</b> </label>

    <input type="text" id="fname" size="20">
    <input type="text" id="lname" size="20">

    <br>
    <label style="margin-left:65px"> First Name </label>
    <label style="margin-left:105px"> Last Name </label>

    <br><br>

    <label><b>Arrival Date:</b></label>
    <input type="date" id="date">

    <br><br>

    <label><b>Room Type:</b></label>

    <select id="room">
      <option></option>
      <option value="King ">King $30</option>
      <option value="Double ">Double $20</option>
      <option value="Single ">Single $10</option>
    </select>

    <br><br>

    <label><b> Number of Days:</b></label>
    <input type="text" size="12" id="days">

    <br><br>

    <label><b> Any Special Request:</b></label>
    <br>
    <textarea rows="5" cols="50" id="request"></textarea>

    <br>


    <button type="reset" STYLE="background-color:red;border:offset;"> CLEAR </button>
    <button type="submit" onClick="return myFunction()" STYLE="background-color:red;border:offset;"> BOOK </button>
  </form>

  <p style="background-color:#cce6ff;width:350px;font-weight: bold;" id="result"> </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has provided `.toUpperCase()` function for String.

```
var fullName = Fname + "   " + Lname;

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = " Dear " + fullName.toUpperCase() + " , thank you for booking with us."+
```